# Allow Specific Cells to be selected when another cell's value is equal to 1 or 2

Tags: excel, vba

This sounds easy but i cant get my code to work for some reason. 
i have a dynamic chart which updates based on cell selected in Column A. i have a dropdown menu that contains 2 items: Element and Subcategory. when the Element item is selected, the cells A9 to 13 gets populated with Element items. when the dropdown is set to Subcategory, the cells A9 to a23 gets popultaed with Subcategory items.

To limit cells that can be selected, i want to lock the worksheet. i can do that by just setting a password for the worksheet however, i also want to be able to lock/unlock the cells with the Elements and Subcategories based on the selection from the dropdown.

that is, if the dropdown is set to Elements, the user should only be able to select cells from A9 to A13. if the dropdown is set to Subcategory, then the user should only be able to select from cells A9 to A23.

the screenshot below is my Dashbboard worksheet. the Dropdown menu is linked to A8 in my Formulas worksheet. i set the dashboard worksheet to locked with a password, im expecting the worksheet to allow me to select the cells in the code when i change the dropdown value but they stay locked.

[image: dashboard]

```
here's the code i put in my Formulas worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wsdashboard2 As Worksheet
Set wsdashboard2 = Sheets("Dashboard2")
    If Range("A8") = "1" Then
        wsdashboard2.Range("A8:A13").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("A8:A23") = "2" Then
        wsdashboard2.Range("A8:A23").Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A8:A23") = "2"` will never be true since an array of values won't be equal to a single string. Also -- are you sure that `Range("A8")` and `Range("A8:A23")` refer to ranges on the intended worksheet? It seems odd that within the exact same sub you qualify some ranges by specifying the worksheet but not other ranges.

Comment: `Range("A8:A23") = "2"` should throw a `Type Mismatch` error. The fact that you haven't mentioned that but are instead merely saying that the code doesn't behave as intended leads me to suspect that you are using `On Error Resume Next` to silence such errors. If so -- removing that statement should be the first step in debugging.